# Unable to find Metadata of nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a nuget package present in a local path. I want to add the reference of that nuget package. But everytime I try to install the package it shows me
Unable to find Metadata of nuget package
Unable to find package. No package exists with this id in source: A, B , C.

What should I do/should check for while installing the package? There is no dependency of the package.

I tried to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/NU1101 reference but didn't help much.
I have checked the nuget.config file and the source mapping is there

Comment: **Exactly** what commands did you run? And exactly what programs and tools are you using? Show us your `.nuspec` and `.csproj` files.

Comment: I just added the new path of the nuget package that is there in my drive. Then from Nuget Package manager I tried to install the package

Comment: _"I just added the new path of the nuget package that is there in my drive."_ - okay, but **exactly** what steps did you take to do that? did you edit your `.csproj` file in a text editor? or did you use the package-manager-console inside VS? or did you use the `nuget` command-line outside of VS? What does your `<PackageReference>` element look like? **Exactly** what error message are you seeing (because NU1101 is not a metadata error)?

Comment: I clicked Manage Nuget Packages -> added a new package source which is having my local nuget package path -> It showed the existing nuget package in that path. and I clicked install. Thats it.
My package reference looks like this - 
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
    <add key="Another Local Source" value="D:\rdcs_nuget\" />
  </packageSources>